# Темы в Wordpress CMS

Tags: css, wordpress, cms

У меня есть сайт, у русской версии тема одна, а у английской другая.

Как то можно копировать тему русского языка и поставить на английский (дизайн)?

Все файлы есть, `wp admin` тоже.

Comment: Ка это разные темы у разных яз.версий? Как всё сделано?

Comment: @SeVlad да мультисайт небось

Comment: Я вот незнаю сам друг есть дал мне сайт переходишь по англ там дизайн другой а по рус другой

Comment: есть доступ ко всем wp themes wp admin т.д поможете?